# How do I have a popup/popover appear when a YouTube video finishes?

Tags: javascript, youtube, popup, modal-dialog

I am trying to figure out a way to trigger a javascript modal popup/popover when a YouTube video finishes.

I first saw this achieved on UpWorthy.com. See this video for an example when the video ends: http://www.upworthy.com/bully-calls-news-anchor-fat-news-anchor-destroys-him-on-live-tv

I have enabled the javascript api by adding the JS parameter to the embed code (enablejsapi=1)

I am using this Simple Modal script to achieve the modal: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

How do I get the end of the youtube video to trigger it?

Many thanks

Comment: do you know what event fires when the youtube video ends? this should be somewhere in the api.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YT Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'ecccag3L-yw',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) { /* do nothing yet */ }

      // The API calls this function when the player's state changes.

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                // insert appropriate modal (or whatever) below
                alert('I hope you enjoyed the video')
        }
      }
      -->

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onStateChange` event of the Youtube Player and check the current player state. If the state is `YT.PlayerState.ENDED` then you can trigger the modal dialog box.

From Youtube JavaScript player api reference document(with some modification)

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById(playerId);
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   if(newState==YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
        //OPEN Modal dialog box here
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tariqulazam , how can I add a modal box to the example you gave above